# Firebase cloud function for sending push notification using topic

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger a push notification whenever a new comment is added under a specific `meetupId` in the `comments` tree in my database. The tree is structured like so:

```
comments:
     (meetupId)
          (commentId)
               -createdBy: String
               -meetupId: String
               -timestamp: Int
               -commentText: String
```

The first comment added on a meetup creates a child under `comments` and all other comments for that meetup are added under that `meetupId` child. I am using the `meetupId` as a topic for this cloud function. So whenever a comment is added to a specific `meetupId` that certain users are subscribed to, I would like the push notification to fire. I am a Swift developer and am totally unfamiliar with JavaScript, so this has been a bit of a struggle for me and I am looking for some help in writing this cloud function.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.meetupNotification = functions.database
.ref('/comments/{meetupId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var sender = snapshot.val().createdBy;
    var content = snapshot.val().commentText;
    var meetupId = snapshot.val().meetupId;

    var topic = meetupId;

    // Notification details and Payload.
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `A new comment was added to a ${topic} you're attending!`,
            body: content,
            badge: badgeCount.toString(),
            sound: 'default'
        },
        data: {
            statusCode: '101',
            senderID: sender,
            meetupID: meetupId,
            content: content,
        }
    };
    const options = {
        priority: 'high',
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);
    console.log('Comment notification for  sent successfully')
});
```

Any guidance and assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are at least four different technologies at work here. What specific part isn't working?

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for your reply. I believe what isn't working is the reference path in my cloud function. I am not sure how to write the proper path for my database structure so that topic var is assigned the meeupId

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What line in the code is that?

Comment: Hey Frank! I apologize for my bad explanation. I believe i have found the problem as i have gotten the notification working. It was this line of code: exports.meetupNotification = functions.database
.ref('/comments/{meetupId}'). I added {commentId} after {meetupId} and it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Good to hear ACerts. If you add that as an answer, others may benefit from it in the future.

Comment: I will definitely do that. Thanks again for your help, Frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference for anyone who might run into a similar problem i got this function working properly by simply adding `{commentId}` to the end of the ref path. So in full it looks like this

```
exports.meetupNotification = functions.database
 .ref('/comments/{meetupId}/{commentId}')
```